# Disable a button in python

Tags: python, arcgis

I am using the python add in for arcgis and I am trying to disable a button when I click in another button. The problem is that my code is not working, Help please!

```
class ButtonSelectRetire(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):        

        cbr = ButtontRetire()
        cbr.off()     

class ButtontRetire(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False

    def onClick(self):
    pass

    def on (self):
        self.enable = True

    def off (self):
        self.enable = False
```

Comment: Should `enable` and `enabled` be different?

Comment: Beside the `enable`/`enabled` mistake, are you aware that with the line `cbr = ButtontRetire()` you create a new instance of the class `ButtontRetire`. Maybe what you want is to retrieve an existing instance of this class and call the `off()` method on it ?

Comment: Thank you debianplebian and Frodon. I will try to find some documentation about instances, I am just beginning with Python so it's giving a hard time.

Comment: Sorry! I couldn't find how to retrieve an existing instance!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wanted to disable `ButtontRetire` with `ButtonSelectRetire` class. Be carefull with intentions. [Here](https://youtu.be/UU0s6b68Cx4?t=4m7s) you can find a short and straightforward pythonaddins
video tutorial for beginners (with answer).

```
class ButtonSelectRetire(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        ButtontRetire.enabled = False

class ButtontRetire(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False

    def onClick(self):
        pass
```